# How to automatically refresh Vim on buffer/window focus?

Tags: vim, gvim

I often use [Control+L to redraw the screen in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117725/how-to-make-vi-redraw-screen).

In particular, when I come out of sleep or change monitor configurations I often find that Vim needs to be redrawn. I thought it might be simpler to just add something to my vimrc that redraws on focus.

- Is there a command that I can add to my `.vimrc` file that redraws the buffer when the window/buffer gets the focus?

In particular, a good command should have no noticeable negative performance or other related side effects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

vim has an event you can bind to for this, `FocusGained`, combine this with the `redraw!` command (the `!` causes the window to be cleared first)

```
:au FocusGained * :redraw!
```

The syntax here can be read as 'automatically run the command (au is short for autocmd) `:redraw!` when I get the event `FocusGained` for any file matching the pattern `*`'.

to make this permanent add it to your `~/.vimrc` (the leading `:` isn't needed in vimrc).

to test events you can use a more 'obvious' command like

```
:au FocusGained * :q!
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a basic test, and it seemed to work without any performance issues.